# Nginx - Host two node servers without accessing port number from the other server

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, express, reverse-proxy

Very new to Nginx here. I have a VPS, where I host two node servers behind Nginx.
(followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab))

`examplesite.com:3838`
`anothersite.com:3839`

I have two `.conf` files for each in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` as follows:

**examplesite.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name examplesite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**anothersite.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name anothersite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3839;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

My problems are that if I go to `examplesite.com:3839`, it serves me `anothersite.com`. Also, if I navigate to the server's IP address, I get `examplesite.com`'s site. Lastly, and most importantly, if I go to `anothersite.com` it serves 'examplesite.com'.

Am I missing something major?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problems are that if I go to examplesite.com:3839, it serves me anothersite.com

This has nothing to do with nginx. You are bypassing nginx entirely here and connecting your browser straight to your express app (because you are putting the port into your browser address bar). So this means you have the wrong express app listening on 3839. Stop that app and start up the anothersite.com express app listening on 3839 and things will start making a lot more sense.

So in general your express apps should bind to the loopback IP with `app.listen(3838, '127.0.0.1', callback)`. This will prevent connections directly to the express apps, which is better from a usability perspective: ports in URLs are basically unheard of for any legitimate web site, and a security perspective: better to let nginx protect your apps from the Internet.

As to what happens when you put an IP address instead of a hostname in your browser, that's a fundamental reality of virtual hosting. virtual hosting means serving multiple web sites with their own domain names on a single server at a single IP address, and it only works with host names in the browser (which then send the HTTP "Host" header, which is the lynchpin that makes virtual hosting possible). So without a hostname, all you can do is arbitrarily select one of you apps to be the default and do `listen 80 default;` in your nginx config. You could also force a redirect to the hostname or respond with a dedicated "hey we don't allow browsing by IP" page if you like (although I haven't seen a site that actually does that).

> Lastly, and most importantly, if I go to anothersite.com it serves 'examplesite.com'.

Double check your work. Are you sure the apps and ports are not crisscrossed? Your example looks fine as long as otherwise everything is correctly configured. When you browse to anothersite.com nginx should proxy that to port 3839 which should be the correct application.

Comment: as for your first part, is this what you're suggesting? http://pastebin.com/ewu73jie

Comment: and as for the crisscrossing, i have `app.set('port')` for each site set to their respective ports (3838, 3839). So I don't understand where this could be conflicting

Comment: ok about the crisscrossing, I'm a moron and forgot to reload nginx. Going to test your first suggestion for the port crossing issue. Thanks so far!

Comment: Yes, that gist is what I'm suggesting. See my edit above as you almost certainly have the wrong express app listening on 3839.

Comment: The sites are in fact running on the correct port, but I can access the other site by hand typing the port. anothersite.com serves the right site, so does examplesite.com. examplesite.com is bound to 3838, while anothersite.com is bound to 3839. I can however access examplesite.com on anothersite.com by hand typing anothersite.com:3838. Does that clear things up? I can update my question if need be.

Comment: I'm feeling your first suggestion of passing the host IP to the listen method might solve my issue. The crisscrossing of the sites was solved  with a simple `nginx -s reload`.

Comment: Right, so now I understand what's happening. Don't bind your actual specific host IP, bind literally '127.0.0.1'. You don't need to expose the express apps directly. Force all traffic to come through nginx. That's the normal thing to do. However, if you really want to be able to put ports in URLs, you'll need to add code to your express apps to redirect requests that arrive with the wrong Host header.

Comment: No ports are needing to be accessed in production. When you say "Don't bind your actual specific host IP" do mean through the `.listen` method in node like you first suggested? Or through the nginx conf?

Comment: the port binding with the IP did the trick once I stopped the forever process and restarted it. Thank you for your help